# How can I extract the substring from a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a repeated `string="I will email you at xxx@gmail.com"` and I want to pull out just the actual email address.

How can I pull just the email out?

Note: Ideally, I'd also like to deal with user-error where the format may be `"I will email you at my email xxx@gmail.com"`.  In this case, the user input "my email xxx@gmail.com" and I just want the email address.

Comment: `string.scan(/easily googlable regex for email here/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively permissive regex that will work with your example:

```
"I will email you at xxx@gmail.com".match(/\b\S+@\S+\b/).to_s
#=> "xxx@gmail.com"
```

See also this [RFC-compliant regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Comment: Great let me check this out -- if someone inputs a bad string for email....it will be nil?

Comment: Since we're casting the MatchData object, it will be empty, not nil. `"not found".match(/\b\S+@\S+\b/).to_s.empty? == true`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
[6] pry(main)> string="I will email you at xxx@gmail.com"
=> "I will email you at xxx@gmail.com"
[7] pry(main)> string.scan(/[A-Za-z\d_\-\.+]+@[A-Za-z\d_\-\.]+\.[A-Za-z\d_\-]+/)
=> ["xxx@gmail.com"]
[8] pry(main)> str2 = "I will email you at my email xxx@gmail.com"
=> "I will email you at my email xxx@gmail.com"
[9] pry(main)> string.scan(/[A-Za-z\d_\-\.+]+@[A-Za-z\d_\-\.]+\.[A-Za-z\d_\-]+/)
=> ["xxx@gmail.com"]
```

There's some good reading on this subject at "[How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)"